# Wrapping Items in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this web page, I'm displaying a list of a variable number of items. I want to layout the items horizontally and wrap to the next line if the item goes past the width of the `item-container`. Currently, I have the [following](http://www.bootply.com/8bMJChhzPD). In this code, I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8bMJChhzPD), the items are just laying vertically. They are not laying out horizontally or wrapping. I cannot use flexbox because I have to support older browsers. I'm trying to make my layout look like this:

```
+-----------+
| █ █ █ █ █ |
| █ █ █ █ █ |
| █ █ █ █ █ |
| █ █ █     |
+-----------+
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS and Bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `.item` inline: `display: inline-block;`

```
.item-wrapper {
  float:left;
  width: 40%;
}

.item {
  height:54px;
  width:54px;
  background-color:orange;
  margin:4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lxefNqBpsM)

Answer (score -1):

To profit of bootstrap you can give the item-wrapper division another class `<div class="item-wrapper col-lg-4">`